# Permanently change color of selected item in listview on button click?

Tags: javafx

How to change color of selected item in listview on button click permanently?

```
apsentButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

        }
    });
```

So, i have apsentButton and listview, and I want to when I select some item from listview and click on button to that selected view become green permanenetly, after click on some other item from listview I want that item that I seleceted first stay green????

Comment: custom cellfactory

Comment: Each item has a button or your button is independent component ?

Answer (score 0):

Save the selected items in a observable collection and use a `cellFactory` returning cells that update on an item change or an update of the list. To choose different colors based on the selection/focus state, it's best to use a CSS stylesheet and `PseudoClass` to do the styling:

```
final PseudoClass marked = PseudoClass.getPseudoClass("marked");

final ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    listView.getItems().add("item " + i);
}

final ObservableSet<String> markedItems = FXCollections.observableSet(new HashSet<>());

Button button = new Button("mark");
button.setOnAction(evt -> markedItems.addAll(listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()));

listView.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<String>() {

    final InvalidationListener l = o -> {
        String item = getItem();
        pseudoClassStateChanged(marked, item != null && markedItems.contains(item));
    };
    final WeakInvalidationListener listener = new WeakInvalidationListener(l);

    {
        markedItems.addListener(listener);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(item);
        l.invalidated(null);
    }

});
```

Stylesheet applied to ancestor/the scene:

```css
.list-cell:marked {
    -fx-base: green;
    -fx-selection-bar: #00FFFF;
    -fx-selection-bar-non-focused: #228822;
}
```